# Trying to show an activity indicator in a custom cell in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, custom-controls, uiactivityindicatorview

I had a custom cell defined in a `xib` file where I later place an `UIActivityIndicatorView` programmatically in a view controller. This was correctly working for iOS 6 and earlier, but I'm not able to see the activity indicator in iOS 7.

I'm doing this way: I firstly register the `nib` in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and if system version is 7.0 or above, I do:

```
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(259, 21, activityIndicator.frame.size.width, activityIndicator.frame.size.height);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

But, as I said, the activity indicator is not shown. Subviews in iOS7 are supposed to be added to cell's `contentView`, am I missing anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the view of xib over contentView. Are you sure contentView is xib_view ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, change the activity indicator color as clear color before animating.

```
[self.activityIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Even its not working,then try to uncheck `Animating` behavior in `attributes inspector` in `IB`

Answer (score 0):

i belive you have created  cell by using interface builder i.e "Customcell" in your case. but added activity indicator by coding in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" which is wrong. Try creating activity indicator using interface builder which is easy and hide it if necessary in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Answer (score 0):

Use `[cell.contentView.view addSubview:activityIndicator]` instead.